# Predicate logic for statements about functions?

Tags: functions, predicate-logic

Given the relation $R$ defined on the cartesian map $A\times A$ where $|A|=n$.

**How to use the predicate logic to express the statements about functions?**

*Examples.*

1. The relation R corresponds to a function from A to A.
2. The relation R corresponds to an injective function from A to A.
3. The relation R corresponds to and bijective function from A to A.

where for each part above respectively I think them as

1. $\forall a\in A$, there exist $c\in A,s.t.(a,b)\in R$.
2. $\forall a,b\in A$, there exist $c,d\in A,s.t. (a,c),(b,d)\in R\& (a\ne b\to c\ne d)$
3. i8t is surjective with the statement in ii).

*Are the above interpretations right?*

Comment: Your answer to i) allows $R$ to contain both $(1,2)$ and $(1,3)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $=$ be the equality predicate. Then the relation $R$ is a function if
$$
\forall x \forall y \forall z: ((x, y) \in R \land (x, z) \in R) \to (y = z).
$$
It is a *total* function if it is a function and
$$
\forall x \exists y: x \in A \to (x, y) \in R.
$$
Usually we omit "total" and assume that all "functions" are total. (Those that are not total are given the adjective "partial".) So I believe you need both statements in your problem.

In order for $R$ to be an injective function, it must be a (total) function and satisfy
$$
\forall x \forall y \forall z: ((x, z) \in R \land (y, z) \in R) \to (x = y).
$$

Finally, in order for $R$ to be a bijective function, it has to be injective and satisfy
$$
\forall y \exists x: y \in A \to (x, y) \in R.
$$

If your quantifiers are always over $A$, predicates for surjectivity and totality can be shortened a little bit. Here's the summary:

- Well-defined: $\forall x \forall y \forall z: ((x, y) \in R \land (x, z) \in R) \to (y = z)$
- Total: $\forall x \exists y: (x, y) \in R$
- Injective: $\forall x \forall y \forall z: ((x, z) \in R \land (y, z) \in R) \to (x = y)$
- Surjective: $\forall y \exists x: (x, y) \in R$
- Being a (total) function: Total and well-defined
- Being an injective (total) function: Total, well-defined and injective
- Being a bijection: Total, well-defined, injective and surjective

Comment: Are you able to explain the trigometric function such as $sin(x)$ in terms of partial function, totality, partial bijection and well-defined for [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1623661/5902)?

Comment: @hhh Yes. In the definition I wrote here, it was implicit that $\forall y \exists x$ means $\forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X$ where $X$ and $Y$ are the domain and the codomain respectively. In fact, a more precise definition of a relation should be a triple $(X, Y, R)$ where $R \subseteq X \times Y$. ($X$ is the domain and $Y$ is the codomain here.)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

i) $\phi:=$"$\forall a\,\exists b:aRb\land \,\big(\forall c: (aRc\Rightarrow b=c)\big)$" 
ii) $\psi:=\phi\land$ "$\forall a,b,c: (aRc\land bRc)\Rightarrow (a=b)$" 
iii) $\vartheta:=\psi\land$ "$\forall b\,\exists a: aRb $"

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't:

The first statement you wrote would be satisfied if the set $A$ were ${1,2}$ and $R$ were defined as ${(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)}$. That is, you need to require also that $b$ is unique.

For the second statement, I think you almost have it but I've usually seen it phrased the other way, that is you start by asserting that $R$ is a function, (using what you said for the first statement) and then say that $c=d \to a=b$. But if you fix your first statement, your way works too.

For the third statement, yes, I'd just say the second statement and surjective (which is just $\forall b \in A, \exists a \in A {\rm s.t.} (a,b) \in R$ )